# copying from a remote server to my hdd with alias or reducing long file paths

Tags: alias, scp

I want to copy files from a remote server to my desktop and vice versa. However, the issue is, my files to be copied from the server have quite long file paths with at least 7-8 subfolders which are more or less constant.

It's hectic to use the entire file path all the time to perform simple copy actions. for eg, if I wanted to copy `filex` from the remote server I would have to type in:

```
scp -r username@remotesrvr.com:/fldr1/fldr2/fldr3/fldr4/..../myfile ./mydesktop
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

One trick that I use constantly is to mount via SSH a remote directory rather than use some cumbersome `scp` command.

#### Example

First mount the remote directory.

```
$ mkdir $HOME/mnt
$ sshfs user@remote:/fldr1/fldr2/fldr3/fldr4/.../myfile $HOME/mnt
```

From this point you can now copy files to/from $HOME/mnt locally and it will be hitting the remote server's directory. Use standard tools such as `cp`, `mv`, etc.

When you're done you can unmount this connection.

```
$ fusermount -u $HOME/mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a package like fileZilla makes it much faster and it does exactly what I want!